# subscribing to data from gazebo plugin

Tags: gazebo, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,i would like to subscribe the hight information and the orientation information of the plugin,that is included within the urdf-file.
here the included part :

```
  <controller:gazebo_ros_p3d name="quadro_groundtruth_sim" plugin="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
    <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
    <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
    <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
    <topicName>ground_truth_pose</topicName>
    <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
    <frameName>map</frameName>
    <interface:position name="my_box_p3d_position_iface" />
  </controller:gazebo_ros_p3d>
```

how can i subscribe this hight information and the orientation information within a node? i tried following.But i don't know how to proceed.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "gazebo_ros_p3d.h"      // is that the header i have to include???

void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");      
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("ground_truth_pose", 1000, chatterCallback);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

But where is my mistake?
thanks,regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12602/subscribing-to-data-from-gazebo-plugin/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2012-01-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I strongly suggest you take a in-depth look at the beginner tutorials, especially [Understanding ROS Topics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics) and
[Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) ones.

I can spot at least two mistakes:

- The subscriber callback has to based on the correct type (not std_msgs:String but nav_msgs/Odometry)
- You have to include the corresponding message header, not gazebo_ros_p3d

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2